# how to get text between : and string?

Tags: ruby

I have a bunch of Strings in an array in the form:

["name: hi", "pw: lol"]

How can I extract just the portion after the semi-colon and space in Ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032440/how-to-split-a-string-in-ruby)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
["name: hi", "pw: lol"].map{|x| x.split(': ')[1]}
```

produces:

```
["hi", "lol"]
```

Comment: If you are not sure if there's always one and only one space after the :, you can split on ':' and then use .strip to remove any whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

The suggestions by Garrett and Peter will definitely do the trick. However, if you want, you can go a step further and easily turn this into a hash.

```
values = ["name: hi", "pw: lol"]
hash = Hash[*values.map{|item| item.split(/\s*:\s*/)}.flatten]
# => {"name"=>"hi", "pw"=>"lol"}
```

There's a lot packed into the second line so let me point out a few improvements:

- The split allows for flexibility in the colon, allowing for any number of spaces both before and after.
- After the `map` call we have the array `[["name", "hi"], ["pw", "lol"]]`
- `Hash#[]` takes a list of values that will be mapped as key, value, key, value,... As a result, we need to flatten the mapped array to pass to `Hash#[]`

Since I don't know your exact needs I can't say whether you want a Hash or not, but it's nice to have the option.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through them and split them up by the `:` like so:

```
["name: hi", "pw: lol"].each do |item|
    puts item.split(":").last.lstrip
end
```

Example:

```
>> a = ["name: hi", "pw: lol"]
=> ["name: hi", "pw: lol"]
>> a.each do |item|
?> puts item.split(":").last.lstrip
>> end

>> hi
>> lol
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use Regular Expressions to process strings, although the previous answers work

> a = ["name: hi", "pw: lol"]
>
> a.map{|item| item.match(/\w+:
>   ([\w\s]+)/)[1]}

this would output:

> => ["hi", "lol"]

Answer (score 0):

```
a.to_s
     h=hi~=a

a.index[h].value
```

or

```
hi{1}
```

Comment: Your answer is not properly formatted. Lines of code should be started with 4 spaces. Also, your answer does not seem to work, please add explanation and/or fix it.